# Do not prolong session expiration when ajax call makes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, extend

I use slidingExpiration session on my web site. And I also added ajax call to check each 15 min session expiration to redirect user on login page. Is it possible to not extend session when this ajax is called?

Comment: I don't know anything about this session expiration mechanism, but you can check if it is ajax call with HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest(), you can write custom ajaxonly attribute for controller actions: http://helios.ca/2009/05/27/aspnet-mvc-action-filter-ajax-only-attribute/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found. To avoid session expiration extend, mark controller by [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] attribute